# RecyclerView item click clicks TextView inside item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textview

My RecyclerView item has a TextView in it and I made the links in TextView clickable using code below in Adapter :

```
public void bindNote(Note note) {
    str = note.getNoteText();
    strHTML = str.replaceAll("\n","<br>");
    noteTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(strHTML));
    noteTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()); 
}
```

The problem is after doing this, now clicking on the item doesn't work properly and it only clicks the item if I click outside the TextView. If I click the text nothing happens.

Is the problem because of the way i made the links clickable? or I'm not handling clicks correctly?

This is a part of ViewHolder :

```
public class NoteViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener,
        View.OnLongClickListener, PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {
    TextView noteTextView;
    TextView dateTextView;

    public NoteViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        noteTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_itemNoteTele_noteText);
        dateTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_itemNoteTele_date);

        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onClickListener.itemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
    }
}

public interface AdapterClickListener {
    void itemClick(View itemView, int position);
}
```

Comment: noteTextView ,dateTextView  of which you need the click, just set a clicklistener

Comment: @ManojPerumarath As you can see I did set a clicklistener for the itemView. I want it to click the item even if I click the text. but if there's a link in TextView, the link should be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the behaviour of your item seems normal and logical. When you click on the textview, it acts as a hyperlink as you configured it.

If you want that click on text give the save action than the item, I suggest you to call the same `View.OnClickListener` for the textview that this of the item

```
public class NoteViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements 
View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener, PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {

TextView noteTextView;
TextView dateTextView;

public NoteViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    noteTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_itemNoteTele_noteText);
    dateTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_itemNoteTele_date);

    itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    noteTextView.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    onClickListener.itemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
  }
}

public interface AdapterClickListener {
void itemClick(View itemView, int position);
}
```

Comment: But I didn't want it to behave like this. I just wanted the links to be clickable. Not the whole TextView. And if I set the onClickListener for the TextView, clicking outside it won't click my item...